# How do I insert a <span> </span> tag inside the <a> </a> tag on my main menu in Drupal7

Tags: templates, drupal-7, html

I'm trying to make the text between my  tag not display by wrapping it in a  and then styling that.

I've added the following function to my template.php file, but I cannot see any difference on the front end. The span just does not appear. (I have cleared my cache)

Am I using the right function? What am I doing wrong?

```
    function my_theme_link($variables) {
  return '<a href="' . check_plain(url($variables['path'], $variables['options'])) . '"' . drupal_attributes($variables['options']['attributes']) . '><span>' . ($variables['options']['html'] ? $variables['text'] : check_plain($variables['text'])) . '</span></a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/how-do-i-insert-a-span-span-tag-inside-the-a-a-tag-on-my-main-menu) on drupal.stackexchange.com and received good answers, if you are interested.